# Creating R packages on Linux server

Tags: r, linux, package

I have a SSH connection to server where I don't have root privileges. Suppose I have some .R file on server in a folder. I want to create a R package using these files. How can I do it ?. On my windows I can do this very easily using RTools. Is there a way I can do it with same easiness on server.
Do I have to install Rtools on server. If yes how? I don't have access to use sudo. R is already installed on server machine by sysadmin.

Comment: There are tons of tutorials that teach you how to build an R package. You don't need root privileges to *build* a package; you need it to *install it globally* (i.e. in such a way that each user can use it). You can however install it in a "private" library. Do some search and you'll build your package in a couple of minutes.

Comment: And as a decent OS Linux includes the necessary tools to build packages mostly out-of-the-box. You don't need to bother with a crutch like Rtools.